# Taking it to the sky/skies

Tags: idioms

I want to use the slogan "Takes your ... to the sky/skies" for an upcoming software-as-a-service (SAAS) platform.

What would be better English:

- Takes your ... to the sky

or

- Takes your ... to the skies

Thanks!

Comment: what is "an upcoming service"? Do you mean a religious service?

Comment: Nothing religious. I updated my question.

Comment: Related: [Using “skies” instead of “sky”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29302)

Answer (score 1):

Either is possible, and neither is "better" English. Skies is somewhat older, and possibly more poetic.

Comment: "Skies is somewhat older". This is not true, as far as I can tell. I just looked it up in the OED and it says "take it to the sky" is [older](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A21232.0001.001/1:2?rgn=div1;view=fulltext). (If you have any evidence that the plural was used in the idiomatic sense earlier than that, please share.)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose either of them. Base on this website, they are all similar: 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20to%20the%20sky/skies

Answer (score 1):

**reach for the moon**[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/reach+for+the+moon)

> To set one's goals or ambitions very high; to try to attain or achieve
>   something particularly difficult

As in:

> Reach for the moom! Our SAAS will indeed take you X there!